# I was trying to run half nested loops and try doing kind of a half sorting of an array but it doesn't seem to work can you tell me why its not working

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, a[n];
    cin >> n;
    float b = n / 2;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cin >> a[i];

    // the code seems to be not working from here till the point marked below
    if (n % 2 == 0)
    {
        for (int k = 1; k <= b; k++)
        {
            for (int j = (b + 1); j <= n; j++)
            {
                if (a[k] > a[j])
                    swap(a[k], a[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    // till this point(pls tell me what's wrong with this part of the code)
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << a[i] << " ";

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A dynamic stack-based array is already a compiler extension, but a post-ex-facto sized dynamic stack-based array is a new one to me.

Comment: C++ arrays are indexed in 0-based way. The first element has index `0`, the last one has index `n - 1` (where `n` is the length of your array). You are accessing your array past-the-end.

Comment: How does one half-nest a loop? It's either in a loop or it isn't.

Comment: Elaborating on my previous comment, it looks like [gcc](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/a97jdxe84)  just sizes the array to whatever happens to be sitting at `[rbp-4]` without even a warning, which seems crazy to me.

Comment: Is *half-sorting* sorting half of the array or is it only performing half of the sorting algorithm?

Comment: `int n, a[n];` <----- n doesn't have a value at that point in the program, so the size of `a` is not clear when `a` starts existing. The compiler should not be happy about this.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i have indexed the array from i=1 till i=n rather than  from i=0 to uptill i=n-1 , i think it is valid i have made other programs that use the same indexing and they still work

Comment: @Frank thanks i got it

Comment: @ThomasMatthews i was just playing with some sorting algos , and i thought of just sorting the  array uptill its half  (an array with even number of integers )

Comment: Use `std::vector` if you don't know the capacity at compile time.  Example **`int a[n];`** ---> `std::vector<int> a;`

Comment: ok thanks @ThomasMatthews